# how can i transmission array to object with lodash?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an array like as below

```
var arr = [ 'type=A', 'day=45' ];
var trans = { 'type': 'A', 'day': 45 }
```

Please write easiest and most efficient way :)

Comment: you need to parse each item in the array to object using split string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could split the string and check if the value [`isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) for string or take the numerical value.

```js
var array = [ 'type=A', 'day=45', 'bar=0' ],
    object = Object.create(null);

array.forEach(function (a) {
    var p = a.split('=');
    object[p[0]] = isNaN(p[1]) ? p[1] : +p[1];
});

console.log(object);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Iterate over each item in the array
2. Split on `=`
3. Add value to object, at key index

```js
var arr = [ 'type=A', 'day=45' ];
var object = {};

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  var currentItem = arr[i].split('=');
  var key = currentItem[0];
  var value = currentItem[1];
  object[key] = value;
}

console.log(object);
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution using [***Array.prototype.reduce()***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function:

```js
var arr = [ 'type=A', 'day=45' ],
    trans = arr.reduce(function(r, s){
        var parts = s.split('=');
        r[parts[0]] = isNaN(parts[1]) ? parts[1] : +parts[1];
        return r;
    }, {});

console.log(trans);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's probably *a million* different ways to this, this way uses two different functions. the `_.map()` call runs on every element, splitting (and parsing) the element (if it matches a character regex). It then uses Lodash's `.fromPairs` function, which converts an array made up of 2 element arrays to return an object.

```js
var arr = ['type=A', 'day=45'];
var obj = _.fromPairs(_.map(arr, function(item) {
  var parts = item.split('=');
  var digits = /^\d+$/;
  if (digits.test(parts[1])) parts[1] = parseInt(parts[1]);
  return parts;
}));
console.log(obj);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```